# Laravel FakeId Page Not Found Error

Tags: php, laravel

I created a simple web form using Laravel 5.1.46.

I've installed and configured- https://github.com/Propaganistas/Laravel-FakeId to obfuscate the model id.

After updating the model and returning to the view, I'm getting this error:

> NotFoundHttpException in FakeIdServiceProvider.php line 90

I followed the instructions to install the package, update providers with the new class, everything seems ok:

> php artisan fakeid:setup - FakeId configured correctly.

RouteServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);

    $router->fakeIdModel('users', 'App\User');
    $router->fakeIdModel('applications', 'App\Application');
}
```

Application.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Propaganistas\LaravelFakeId\FakeIdTrait;

class Application extends Model
{
    use FakeIdTrait;
    ...
}
```

ApplicationController.php

```
public function update(Request $request, Application $application)
{
    $input = array_except(Input::all(), '_method');
    //Updating application info
    $application->update($input);

    return view('application.application_edit', compact('application'))->with('message', 'Success_Update');
}
```

routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function ()
{
    //Application
    Route::resource('applications', 'ApplicationController');
    Route::post('applications', 'ApplicationController@index');

});
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you making request to `applications.index` route ?

Comment: Not right now, but that doesn't seem to affect, I commented the line and i'm still getting the same error.